# Users can't save advanced finds (views) in CRM Dynamics 4

Tags: dynamics-crm-4

We've recently created a new deployment in our CRM Dynamics 4 environment.

In this new deployment users in roles other than System Admin can't save their own views. They can open Advanced Find and create a query, run it, and see the correct results. However, the 'save' and 'save as' buttons are greyed out.

The first deployment has no issues, and the permissions are almost identical.

According to MS docs, all users should be able to save their own personal views. There is nothing in the docs about permissions on views. Changing the 'Customization' -> View entry in the Security Role doesn't seem to make a difference.

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the "Saved View" class under Core Records.